# Using data from arduino in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, arduino

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ek_zıplama
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        right,
        left,
        up,

    }

    private Directions car_direction;

    public SerialPort myPort;


    int G = 15;
    int force;


    bool jump;

   public string DATA;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myPort = new SerialPort();
        myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        myPort.PortName = "COM6";
        myPort.Open();

        jump = false;
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        moves();

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (jump)
        {
            car.Top -= force;
            force -= 1;
        }



       //using block to stay in same position when car is stopped
        if (car.Left + car.Width - 1 > block.Left && car.Left + car.Width + 5 < block.Left + block.Width + car.Width
            && car.Top + car.Height >= block.Top && car.Top < block.Top)
        {
            car.Top = ekran.Height - block.Height - car.Height;
            force = 0;
            jump = false;
        }


    }




    private void moves()
    {

        if (label2.Text == "10111" && car_direction != Directions.right)
        {
            car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X + 130, car.Location.Y);
            car_direction = Directions.right;
        }

        if (label2.Text == "01111" && car_direction != Directions.left)
        {
            car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X - 130, car.Location.Y);
            car_direction = Directions.left;
        }

        if (!jump && label2.Text == "11011")
        {
            jump = true;
            force = G;
        }

    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DATA = myPort.ReadExisting();

        label2.Text = DATA;


    }
  }
 }
```

What I botch about that in move function.
I tried to create a function like
*if DATA is 01111 then my car turns left
*if DATA is 10111 then my car turns right
*if DATA is 11011 then my car jumps

Before I changed,car was controlled with keyboards.Everything was same but "move"function.And it was working.What were instead od "move" function is:

```
   private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right&& car_direction != Directions.right)
    {
        car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X + 130, car.Location.Y);
        car_direction = Directions.right;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && car_direction != Directions.left)
    {
        car.Location = new Point(car.Location.X - 130, car.Location.Y);
        car_direction = Directions.left;
    }

    if (!jump && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        jump = true;
        force = G;
    }

}
```

Hope you get me :)

Comment: The controling with keys sounds good to me. Why did you change it and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure it's not going to work if you only call it once in your Form_Load event. Since you maybe want your `car` to move each time the data in the label has changed, you should just make a reference to the function you created. That means, that you should just put `moves();` in `private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DATA = myPort.ReadExisting();

    label2.Text = DATA;

    moves();
}
```

In this way, each time the timer ticks, your car is going to move according to the new data in the label.

Comment: sorry it didn't work.But thanks a lot for your attention :)

Comment: I tried to ask you for some further info about your code in the comments, since I'm not sure how everything functionates.
Maybe you'd like to debug a bit... Why do you even need to set the label text since you already have that DATA string globalized. Anyway, are you sure it returns the proper codes you're looking for? Is the if statement even getting fulfilled or not?

Comment: Because first I just wanted to be sure that whether I receive data from arduino or not.I think what my problem is converting my DATA to something but still not sure.

Comment: Should be. Take a careful look at the way you're receiving data and the format it is in.

Comment: It is string.So should I convert to Int16,Int32 or something? thanks

Comment: There is no problem if it is a string, the matter is what it contains and how can you find out if the user wants to move right/left or jump. With other words, check out if the DATA is really the strings you're checking in your code.

Comment: Yes :D when I debugged it I saw that my DATA value is "01111\r \n" but I though it was just "01111".So it is solved thanks a lot for your help again

Comment: @CerenCerengil You can always use a Regex pattern to clean all the white space chars `\s` from your string. I think you'll know it already. Glad I've helped! (You can always mark the answer tho :D)

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing something with Arduino I used something like this:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort != null && serialPort.IsOpen && serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        data_as_string += serialPort.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how `DATA` is sent, but you can send single lines from Arduino using `Serial.write("your line here");`. Receiving and parsing data from here is very simple, as you could just read lines `01111`, `10111`, etc. and use any logic to manipulate the car. I hope this helps.